# Using n_distinct for Postgres tables

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, dbplyr

I am trying to interact with Postgres table using `dplyr` and `dbplyr` without collecting (pulling) the data into R.
If a table is formatted like x below, how could I calculate the count of distinct values within my defined groupings?

For instance, this example is to mimic what I want to do:

```
# Would actually be x = tbl(src = "postgres_conn", "x")

x = data.frame(
    a = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
    b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
    c = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
)

> x
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 2
3 2 1 3
4 2 2 1
5 3 2 2
6 3 2 3

x %>% group_by(a, b) %>% mutate(Count = n_distinct(c))

# Results
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   a, b [4]
      a     b     c Count
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     1     2
2     1     1     2     2
3     2     1     3     1
4     2     2     1     1
5     3     2     2     2
6     3     2     3     2
```

If I use n_distinct(c) on Postgres tbl, I get the following error: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions.
I tried length(unique(c)), which returned a syntax error.

Trying

```
sql('COUNT(DISTINCT(c))')
```

gives me this error:

```
column "c" does not exist. HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "aresphukou.c."
```

However, aresphukou is an arbitrary temp table name that changes each time I run the query.

Lastly, I tried `replyr_uniqueValues`, but it seemed to ignore the groupings and returned value of 1 for all the Count values.

Could anyone suggest how this problem could be tackled?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question by chance after nearly four years. Using dbplyr/dplyr you might not get the desired response, but with PostgreSQL, you can achieve that by joining the results from a subquery or CTE (common table expression) with the x table:

```
with y as (
select a, b, count(c) as n
from x
group by a,b
)
select a, b, c, n
from x
left join y using (a,b);
```